# Mysior plane is not realcompact

Tags: gn.general-topology, ultrafilters, realcompact-spaces

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ with $(x, y)\in X$ for $y\neq 0$ isolated and $(x, 0)$ having neighbourhood basis of the form $$U_n(x) = \{(x, y) : y\in (-1/n, 1/n)\}\cup \{(x+y+1, y) : 0 < y < 1/n\}\cup \{(x+\sqrt{2}+y, -y) : 0 < y < 1/n\}.$$ The space $X$ is called Mysior plane, and it's an example of a space which is a union of two closed subspaces, $X_+ = \mathbb{R}\times [0, \infty)$ and $X_- = \mathbb{R}\times (-\infty, 0]$, which are realcompact, but isn't itself realcompact.

Since the map $f:X_+\sqcup X_-\to X$ is perfect, this shows realcompactness is not invariant under perfect mappings.

The space $X$ is Tychonoff: Say $(x, y), (w, t)\in X$. If $y\neq 0$ or $t\neq 0$ this is quite obvious since one of the points is isolated. If $y = t = 0$, and $x < w$, then by splitting into three cases $x < w \leq x+1, x+1 < w \leq x+\sqrt{2}$ and $w\geq x+\sqrt{2}$ one can easily see that we have disjoint neighbourhoods. Thus $X$ is Hausdorff. If $(x, y)\notin F$ and $F$ is closed, of course the only interesting case is when $y = 0$ for otherwise $\{(x, y)\}$ is clopen. In that case we can find $n$ with $U_n(x)\subseteq F^c$. By defining $f(w, t) = 1$ for $(w, t)\notin U_n(x)$ and $f(w, t) = nt$ for $(w, t)\in U_n(x)$, we see that $f$ is continuous and so $X$ is Tychonoff.

To see that $X_+$ and $X_-$ are realcompact, lets focus on $X_+$. If $\mathcal{F}$ is a real z-ultrafilter on $X_+$, then since $\mathbb{R}\times [0, a]$ for $a > 0$ is clopen, we can see that if $\mathbb{R}\times (a, \infty)\in\mathcal{F}$, then $\mathcal{F}\restriction_{\mathbb{R}\times (a, \infty)}$ is a real z-ultrafilter on the realcompact space $\mathbb{R}\times (a, \infty)$, and as such is fixed, so that $\mathcal{F}$ is fixed. Otherwise, if for all $a > 0$, $\mathbb{R}\times [0, a]\in \mathcal{F}$, then $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}\in\mathcal{F}$ since $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under countable intersections. One can observe that $([a, b]+\mathbb{Z})\times \{0\}$ for $a < b$ are zero sets of $X_+$ by construction appropriate functions (similar to the one in the proof that $X$ is Tychonoff). Thus $([0, 1/2]+\mathbb{Z})\times \{0\}\in \mathcal{F}$ or $([1/2, 1]+\mathbb{Z})\times\{0\}\in \mathcal{F}$, for example the former case holds. Take $a = \sup \{x\in [0, 1/2] : ([x, 1/2]+\mathbb{Z})\times\{0\}\in \mathcal{F}\}$ and $b = \inf\{x\in [a, 1/2] : ([a, x]+\mathbb{Z})\times\{0\}\in\mathcal{F}\}$. Once again one would show that $[a, b]+\mathbb{Z}\in \mathcal{F}$ from closure under countable intersections, and if $a\neq b$ we could take $a < c < b$ and by considering $([a, c]+\mathbb{Z})\times\{0\}$ and $([c, b]+\mathbb{Z})\times\{0\}$ obtain a contradiction with choice of $a, b$. Thus $(a+\mathbb{Z})\times\{0\}\in\mathcal{F}$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$. However, since $(a+\mathbb{Z})\times\{0\} = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\{(a+n, 0)\}$ is a countable union of zero sets, and since $\mathcal{F}$ is a real z-ultrafilter, we must have $\{(a+n, 0)\}\in\mathcal{F}$ for some $n$, that is $\mathcal{F}$ is a fixed z-ultrafilter. This proves $X_+$ is realcompact, the proof for $X_-$ is the same.

Could anyone help me on how to show that $X$ is not realcompact?

**Edit:** A z-ultrafilter is an ultrafilter on the lattice of zero sets (as to distinguish them from ultrafilters on the lattice of sets), and a real z-ultrafilter is a z-ultrafilter closed under countable intersections.

[Crossposted with math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718866/mysior-plane-is-not-realcompact).

**Edit 2:** The reason why I reposted my question here, is that I think only small amount of people on math.stackexchange know what realcompactness is. I want to gain exposure to knowledgeable people that have a higher chance to help me and maybe even know the example I'm talking about. The original paper this comes from is "A union of realcompact spaces" by A. Mysior. All books and articles only briefly mention this example (e.g. Engelking and plethora articles about realcompactness and various alternatives). My guess is that the $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are there for a reason, and I tried to consider what would happen if e.g. $f\in C(X)$ were $0$ on $[0, 1]\times \{0\}$, because it seems like maybe I could prove that a zero set containing this will contain $[1, 2]\times \{0\}$ and $[\sqrt{2}, 1+\sqrt{2}]\times\{0\}$ etc., but I feel like while $f$ on $U_n(x)$ for $x\in [0, 1]$ must approach $0$ as $n$ gets larger, they can do so at distinct rates for all $x$, hence my difficulties. Overall, my first intuition would be to figure out the zero sets contained in $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$.

Comment: Were you able to get hold of the original article? (The *Bulletin de l'Académie Polonaise des Sciences, Série des Sciences Mathématiques, Astronomiques et Physiques* only seems to have the issues since 2004 online, and I don't have access to a library which would have the paper version.) If yes, does it not give an argument?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen sadly I didn't get a hold of the article, but I suspect it does give an argument. I do know where one physical copy is located, so I might check this in the future, but I suspect that the answer below is probably the "canonical" answer (that is to show that any zero set in $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ is either meager or comeager in $\mathbb{R}$ with Euclidean topology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof that I can think of applies a Baire-category argument to the normal topology of the real line.
As in your argument for realcompactness you need to look at zero-sets that are subsets of the $x$-axis. Let $Z_f$ be such a zero-set, and look at $Z=\{x:f(x,0)=0\}$. There are two cases: (1) every nonempty open interval contains a nonempty open interval in which $Z$ is of first category (union of countably many nowhere dense sets), or (2) there is an open interval $(a,b)$ such that for no subinterval $(p,q)$ of $(a,b)$ the intersection $Z\cap(p,q)$ is of first category in $(p,q)$.
In the first case you can show that $Z$ is of first category in $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the second case; we show that $(a+1,b+1)\setminus Z$ and $(a+\sqrt2,b+\sqrt2)\setminus Z$ are both of first-category.
Let $\varepsilon>0$. For every $x\in(a,b)\cap Z$ there is an $n_x$ such that $f[U_{n_x}(x)]\subseteq(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$.
Let $(p,q)$ be a subinterval of $(a,b)$, by our assumption there is an $n$ such that $F=\{x\in(p,q)\cap Z:n_x=n\}$ is not nowhere dense, that is there is a further subinterval $(r,s)$ of $(p,q)$ that is contained in the closure (in the normal topology of $\mathbb{R}$) of $F$.
Let $x\in(r,s)$ and take an increasing sequence $\langle t_k\rangle$ in $F$ that converges to $x$. Now check that $U_m(x+1)$ interesects $U_n(t_k)$ for infinitely many $k$; this implies that $|f(x+1,0)|\le\varepsilon$; similarly you'll find that $|f(x+\sqrt2,0)|\le\varepsilon$.
This shows that the sets $O_1(\varepsilon)=\{x\in(a,b):|f(x+1, 0)|\le\varepsilon\}$ and $O_2(\varepsilon)=\{x\in(a,b):|f(x+\sqrt2, 0)|\le\varepsilon\}$ both contain dense open subsets of $(a,b)$.
Now let $D=\bigcap_m\bigl(O_1(2^{-m})\cap O_2(2^{-m})\bigr)$ then $(a,b)\setminus D$ is of first-category and for all $x\in D$ we have $f(x+1,0)=f(x+\sqrt2,0)=0$.

Using simlar methods you can show that $(a-1,b-1)\setminus Z$ and $(a-\sqrt2,b-\sqrt2)\setminus Z$ are both of first-category.
Now use the fact that $\{a+m+n\sqrt2:m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ to see that, in fact, the complement of $Z$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is of first category.

So a zero-set contained in the $x$-axis either is of first-category in $\mathbb{R}$ or its complement is. The latter form a zero-set ultrafilter with the countable intersection property but with an empty intersection.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you had in mind, but to prove that in the first case $Z$ is meager, if $D(A)$ denotes the set of points of $\mathbb{R}$ for which there's no neighbourhood $U$ such that $U\cap A$ is meager, then one can prove $A\setminus D(A)$ is meager, and so from our assumption $D(Z)$ is meager, so $Z = Z\setminus D(Z)\cup D(Z)$ is meager.

Comment: I just wanted to take a maximal disjoint family of (rational) intervals $I_n$ such that each intersection $Z\cap I_n$ would be of first category; the complement of $\bigcup_n I_n$ is nowhere dense and $\bigcup_n(Z\cap I_n)$ is of first category.

Comment: I believe the argument to show that the $z$-filter $\mathcal{F}$ generated by the comeager (as subsets of real line) zero sets in $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ is a $z$-ultrafilter is as follows: if $Z = Z(f)\subseteq\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ is meager, then $\{|f|\leq \frac{1}{n}\}\cap \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ is either comeager for all $n$, thus $Z$ is comeager (since $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under countable intersections), which is impossible, or there is $n$ for which it's meager. Then $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}\cap\{|f|\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$ is a comeager set disjoint from $Z$, so $Z\notin \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Not quite: you'd have to establish the dichotomy "either meager or co-meager" first. That is what my argument is about: it starts from "not meager" and deduces "co-meager". That is not automatic.

Comment: Yes, that's what I assumed we already have. Thank you.